# Why does explicit definition of a variable work to call a function but an iterator will not?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

This python script returns a value of `90.0`:

```
import itertools

a=[12,345,1423,65,234]
b=[234,12,34,1,1,1]
c=[1,2,3,4]

def TestFunction (a, b, c):
    result = a + b/c
    return result

Params=itertools.product(a, b, c)

x = 2
print(TestFunction(*list(Params)[x]))
```

However, I would like to evaluate my function for a range of x as:

```
for x in range (5):
    print(TestFunction(*list(Params)[x]))
```

I expected this to return a sequence of values: `246.0`, `129.0`, `90.0`, `70.5`, `14.0`; however, I get:

> "IndexError: list index out of range."

Why does the function evaluate when `x` is defined explicitly but not when it is an iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in range (5):
    print(TestFunction(*list(Params)[x]))
```

`Params` is an iterator. The first time through the loop, you consume it entirely by converting it to a list. Therefore on the second iteration there's nothing in it and converting it to a list yields `[]`, the empty list, and trying get index 1 of that won't work.

Instead, convert the iterator to a list *outside* the loop.

```
params = list(Params)
for x in range(5):
    print(TestFunction(*params[x]))
```

Comment: Ah well that explains the empty lists I was getting while trying to figure this out. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Because calling `list()` on the iterator exhausts the iterator. Thus it can be called once only:

```
>>> Params=itertools.product(a, b, c)
>>> Params
<itertools.product object at 0x7f5ed3da5870>
>>> list(Params)
[(12, 234, 1), (12, 234, 2)..., (234, 1, 4)]
>>> list(Params)
[]
```

You can see that the second call to `list(Params)` evaluates to an empty list, and attempting to subscript that raises an `IndexError`.

You could store the values from the iterator in another variable:

```
l = list(Params)
```

and then access it as you want, accessing arbitrary items by subscript.

If you want to access the items sequentially, as per your for loop example, just call `next()` on the iterator:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(TestFunction(*next(Params)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `Params` is an iterator and converting it to a list consumes it entirely.

There are 2 methods to handle your case:

1. Convert the iterator to a list outside of loop:

   ```
   Params = list(itertools.product(a, b, c))
   ```
2. Use `copy.copy`:

   ```
   from copy import copy
   print(TestFunction(*list(copy(Params))[x]))
   ```

Most of the time Method 1 is appropriate. Occasionally you may want Method 2.